# Bootstrap - Carousel in half of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to use Bootstrap  carousel in half of page (in Desktop). Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="carousel-homepage" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-homepage" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-homepage" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-homepage" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1600x1600" /></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1600x1600" /></a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/1600x1600" /></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-homepage" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-homepage" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 low-padding-left"></div>
```

And here is my result :

[image]

I want to put carousel completely in half of page. Any suggestion?

Comment: Remove padding from first `.col-md-6` div or add `style="padding:0"`

Comment: Put it as answer . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove padding from first `.col-md-6` div or add `style="padding:0"`